# Three-product co-occurrence matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multilinear-algebra

Suppose a matrix $A$ where each row represents a transaction, and each column represents an SKU (product). Each cell is either 1 or 0, meaning whether a product was purchased in a transaction. Product pair (two-product) co-occurrence matrix is essentially $A^TA$.

However, I'm stuck with three (and maybe more) products co-occurrence. By analogy I would expect to get a 3-D "matrix", but I cannot think of any linear algebra operations that produce 3-D matrices out of 2-D.

(By counter example, it is easy to show that three-product co-occurrence is not chaining two product pairs.)

Comment: So, your 3d matrix would get the number of common transactions for products $p_1,p_2,p_3$ as an entry?

Comment: @Berci Exactly. A 3-d matrix is just the most intuitive way to store the result that I can think of; if your approach doesn't produce a 3-d matrix but something else, that's also okay.

Comment: Well, forgetting matrices, we can write up some formula for this, however, I see no way to relate it to the phenomenon of matrix operations $A^TA$ which works for the (two-fold) co-occurences..

Comment: Are you talking about loops (or loop-alikes)? An advantage of the matrix solution over looping for (product pair) co-occurrence is we have ready-to-use software libraries to do the computation **in parallel** (e.g. Apache Mahout). This is important when the matrix is large (which is not unusual when you have millions of transactions and tens of thousands of SKUs).

Comment: That being said, please feel free to add your answer even though if might not relate to matrices (and edit my question if necessary).

Comment: From an engineering perspective, this problem can be solved using classic MapReduce. I will probably elaborate that into an answer (if not off-topic), however this approach requires many lines of code and is obviously not as concise as the linear algebra.